# Recordset is not updateable when try from form but work fine if only subform loaded

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with datasheet subform. When I try to load the main form and update some of the fields in the subform it gives me the error : (Recordset is not updateable)

but when I load the subform by itself it works fine. Iam using Access 2007.

Code under one of the files is:

```
Private Sub No_open_quality_issues_Click()
If (Me.No_open_quality_issues.Value = True) Then
    Me.No_open_quality_issues.Locked = True
End If
End Sub
```

it looks like the problem happen when I change the source record source from :

```
SELECT Production_Readiness.*
FROM Production_Readiness;
```

To :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Production_Readiness.*
FROM Production_Readiness
WHERE (((Production_Readiness.Material) Like '' & "*" Or (Production_Readiness.Material) Is Null) AND ((Production_Readiness.[All Engine Models]) Like '' & "*" Or (Production_Readiness.[All Engine Models]) Is Null) AND ((Production_Readiness.Commodities) Like '' & "*" Or (Production_Readiness.Commodities) Is Null) AND ((Production_Readiness.[Buyer Name]) Like '' & "*" Or (Production_Readiness.[Buyer Name]) Is Null) AND ((Production_Readiness.Vendor) Like '' & "*" Or (Production_Readiness.Vendor) Is Null) AND ((Production_Readiness.[Vendor Name]) Like '' & "*" Or (Production_Readiness.[Vendor Name]) Is Null) AND ((Production_Readiness.[MinOfStat-Rel Del Date     Next coming delivery])>=#5/16/1892# And (Production_Readiness.[MinOfStat-Rel Del Date     Next coming delivery])<=#3/15/2016#) AND ((Production_Readiness.[Buyer Badge])=FctUserID()) AND ((Production_Readiness.Status)<>'Processed'));
```

to be more specific it happen when I try to use this function on loading the form :

```
Private Function LoadHOQuery()

progComb_Filter = "Like '' & ""*"" Or (Production_Readiness.[All Engine Models]) Is Null"
partNoCmb_Filter = "Like '' & ""*"" Or (Production_Readiness.Material) Is Null"
commodCmb_Filter = "Like '' & ""*"" Or (Production_Readiness.Commodities) Is Null"
custCmb_Filter = "Like '' & ""*"" Or (Production_Readiness.[Buyer Name]) Is Null"
subCodeCmb_Filter = "Like '' & ""*"" Or (Production_Readiness.[Vendor]) Is Null"
subCmb_Filter = "Like '' & ""*"" Or (Production_Readiness.[Vendor Name]) Is Null"
startDateTxt_Filter = "5/16/1892"
endDateTxt_Filter = Date
Dim sqlCmd As String

Dim isFormLoades As Boolean
If (openCondition = "Buyer") Then
    isFormLoades = IsLoaded("Handoff_Frm")
    If (isFormLoades) Then
        sqlCmd = "SELECT DISTINCT Production_Readiness.* " & _
                 "FROM Production_Readiness " & _
                 "WHERE (((Production_Readiness.Material) " & partNoCmb_Filter & ") AND ((Production_Readiness.[All Engine Models]) " & progComb_Filter & ") AND " & _
                        "((Production_Readiness.Commodities) " & commodCmb_Filter & " ) AND ((Production_Readiness.[Buyer Name]) " & custCmb_Filter & " ) AND " & _
                        "((Production_Readiness.Vendor) " & subCodeCmb_Filter & ") AND ((Production_Readiness.[Vendor Name]) " & subCmb_Filter & ") AND " & _
                        "((Production_Readiness.[MinOfStat-Rel Del Date     Next coming delivery])>=#" & startDateTxt_Filter & "#) AND ((Production_Readiness.[MinOfStat-Rel Del Date     Next coming delivery])<=#" & endDateTxt_Filter & "#) And" & _
                        "(((Production_Readiness.[Buyer Badge])=FctUserID()) And ((Production_Readiness.[Status]) <>  'Processed') ) ); "

        'MsgBox sqlCmd


        Me.ManageHanOff.Form.RecordSource = sqlCmd
        Me.ManageHanOff.Form.Requery
     End If
 ElseIf (openCondition = "Manager") Then

 End If
```

End Function

Can you help me.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a parent/child relationship set on the main form?

Comment: Yes when some of the fields on the child satisfy some constraint. The parent buttons enabled/disabled depending on this value.

Comment: Could you provide the control sources for the form and subform and the parent/child field with any pertinent table relationships?

Comment: Can you give me more details on that. Also when I try to export documentation for the form and sub form when the form is open I got the following error : application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: I don't need the documentation, just the code that sits in the control source box in the properties pane (on the data tab) of the main form and the subform. The parent/child is in the properties pane too. That's the only way anyone will be able to diagnose the issue. Post an edit to your question including the code and where you pulled it from.

Comment: @ Christopher D. After a lot of testing I found out that the cause is the select stmnt mentioned in the update question.
I need it this way to use it in a search function later but not sure why it cause this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error and it was actually logic one. The problem in the DISTINCT. This is why I can not update because it is more then one record with the same values and the access have no clue which to update.